# Add class on window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, toggle

I would to toggle the class if the windowsize is over 299 and only add the class when the window is smaller. Somehow it is now working and I have no idea why.

Thanks for your help !

Greetings
Ben

**Code fore the windowsize :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var eventFired = 0;
  function windowSize() {
    windowHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
    windowWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
  } 
  windowSize();
```

**if statement :**

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
    windowSize();
    //console.log('width is :', windowWidth, 'Height is :', windowHeight);
    if (windowWidth > 299) {
    $('#topBarToggler, #toggleheading').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#content").click(function () {
        $('#topBarToggler, .toggleheading').prop('checked', true);
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
    });
} else {
    $('#topBarToggler, #toggleheading').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
}

}
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will not be able to use `windowHeight` or `windowWidth` as they are out of Scope. They are defined in the function and cannot be called outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```
function windowSize() {
  return {
    height: window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height(),
    width: window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width()
  };
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var wSize = windowSize();
  if (wSize.width > 299) {
    $('#topBarToggler, #toggleheading').on('click', function (event) {
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#content").click(function () {
      $('#topBarToggler, #toggleheading').prop('checked', true);
      $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
    });
  } else {
    $('#topBarToggler, #toggleheading').on('click', function () {
      $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
    });
  }
});
```

As you can see, an Object is created and returned with two indexes: `width`, `height`. You caa run this function and gather the needed details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ye this makes sence. I will try it out asap.